# More formal alternative of "good" for describing some work

Tags: synonyms, vocabulary, formality

What is a more formal alternative of saying "good" for describing a work? e.g. "The work looks good." 
I don't want an adjective with more intensity than "good" such as "remarkable", "outstadning", etc.
Ideally, an alternative with the same intensity as good, but more formal.

Comment: **"Exciting"** is a word often used this way in business environments. It seems to mean 'potentially rewarding' in a financial sense, as well as the emotional effect associated with the word. *"That new office block project sounds like a very exciting opportunity."* (yawn)

Answer (score 1):

Sound work; quality work; something more specific (well-researched, soundly constructed, appropriately designed).